# Change Wrap Strategy in Google Sheets with Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to change Wrap Strategy programmatically? I've already tried with

[batch_update_spreadsheet documentation](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/SheetsV4/SheetsService.html#batch_update_spreadsheet-instance_method)

```
service.batch_update_spreadsheet
```

and
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961373/how-to-use-wrap-strategy-in-python-for-google-sheets)

```
batch_update
```

but neither worked.

It always return `Invalid Request`.
My request, as I understand from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#wrapstrategy), is just

`service.batch_update_spreadsheet([{ 'wrapStrategy': 'WRAP' }])`

What am I doing wrong? I want to change all cells from my sheet.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the complete sample? You need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From `service.batch_update_spreadsheet([{ 'wrapStrategy': 'WRAP' }])` and `I want to change all cells from my sheet.`, I guessed that your goal is as follows.

- You want to reflect `'wrapStrategy': 'WRAP'` to a sheet in a Google Spreadsheet using googleapis for ruby.
- You have already been able to get and put values to Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```rb
spreadsheet_id = '###' # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_id = '###' # Please set your sheet ID.

request_body = {
  requests: [{repeat_cell: {
    range: {
      sheet_id: sheet_id,
    },
    cell: {
      user_entered_format: {
        wrap_strategy: 'WRAP'
      }
    },
    fields: 'userEnteredFormat.wrapStrategy'
  }}]
}
service.batch_update_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_id, request_body, {})
```

- When this script is run, the wrapStrategy of `sheet_id` is set as `WRAP`.
- In this case, please use the snake case for the keys instead of the camel case. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that your client of `service` can be used for updating the spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)